# MAX(text) returns Operand data type text is invalid for max operator. in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, sqldatatypes

I use `text` data type in one of my tables and also I use `PIVOT` with the query too.
I am unable to use `MAX(AttributeValue)` where `AttributeValue` is the type of `text`. It returns the following error `Operand data type text is invalid for max operator.`. How can I use it here, because I am imposed to use an `aggregate` function with `PIVOT`.

Edit: 
I followed the post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

I tried to convert the data type to `nvarchar(max)`.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ALTER COLUMN AttributeValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Also I have to use `Full Text Search` option too. I get the following error
`Cannot alter or drop column 'AttributeValue' because it is enabled for Full-Text Search.`

```
SELECT 
 [6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4] DOB
,[F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A] CaseTitle 
FROM MyTable PIVOT 
(   MAX(AttributeValue) 
    FOR AttributeID IN 
    (
         [6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4]
        ,[F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A]
    ) 
) ResultTable
```

Where the 'AttributeValue' is of 'text' data type. I get the following error,

Operand data type text is invalid for max operator.

Well, I tried to cast the field to nvarchar(max). It gives another type of error(in the fourth line).

```
Incorrect syntax near '('
```

Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast your text column to varchar(max).

```
select max(cast(AttributeValue as varchar(max)))
from YourTable
```

You can convert your data in a sub query.

```
SELECT 
 [6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4] DOB
,[F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A] CaseTitle 
FROM ( SELECT AttributeID, 
              CAST(AttributeValue as VARCHAR(MAX)) as AttributeValue
       FROM MyTable
     ) AS T
  PIVOT 
(   MAX(AttributeValue) 
    FOR AttributeID IN 
    (
         [6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4]
        ,[F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A]
    ) 
) ResultTable
```

Answer (score 2):

If what I remember is correct, text in SQL Server doesn't let you run a lot of commands against it. The only (half) solution I have come across is casting text to a different data type; unfortunately, this can mean writing some code, and only dealing with the actual stored text data in sections.

Plus, text is being removed from future versions of SQL Server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

So, just alter the column data type to NVarChar(Max), and hopefully the query will run properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [DATALENGTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) within MAX() to avoid casting potentially very large strings.

```
SELECT 
  6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4] DOB
 ,[F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A] CaseTitle 
FROM MyTable PIVOT 
(   MAX(DATALENGTH(AttributeValue)) 
    FOR AttributeID IN 
    (
         [6B93119B-263B-4FED-AA89-198D26A3A3C4]
        ,[F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A]
    ) 
) ResultTable
```